# Change file permission for multiple file paths in a file

Tags: linux, puppet, file-permissions, chmod

I have a file which stores multiple file paths in the file content, as such:

```
$ cat /var/tmp/sample
/etc/ssl/example/ssl-test1.cert
/etc/ssl/example/ssl-test2.cert
/etc/ssl/example/ssl-test3.cert
...
```

Is there a single line command to loop the file paths in the file and set the permission for each of the file paths `chmod 644 <file paths in /var/tmp/sample>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to use xargs:

```
cat /var/tmp/sample | xargs -d '\n' chmod 644
```

Comment: This is nice because you can put filters into the pipeline (e.g. `grep`)

Comment: It's a [useless cat](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2002). Instead of opening two pipes, you could do `grep -v 'filter' filepaths | xargs -d '\n' chmod 644` or if the command only reads stdin `grep -v 'filter' < filepaths | xargs -d '\n' chmod 644`

Comment: @Nobody, you're correct, and your point is especially important if writing a script. However, in the day to day, I hardly ever bother with it, mainly because I usually get the files from `find` and not from a file. I'd be doing something like `find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644`, usually with a more complicated find command...

Comment: @LuisGuzman of course it's better to use nullbytes as delimiters when possible.

Answer (score 3):

Use `xargs`.

```
xargs -d '\n' chmod 644 < /var/tmp/sample
```

Comment: xargs is the way to go, better than a while/read loop, but you can also do `xargs -a /var/tmp/sample -d '\n' chmod 644`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: use `xargs -a /var/tmp/sample -d '\n' chmod 644`

---

You could read the file line-by-line

```
while read -r filen; do
    chmod 644 -- "${filen}"
done < /var/tmp/sample
```

And if it has to be just one line

```
while read -r filen; do chmod 644 -- "${filen}"; done < /var/tmp/sample
```

This gets problematic when a filename contains newlines though.

---

**DO NOT** do this, but if for some reason you don't want to use while/read, you could do

```
chmod 644 -- $(</var/tmp/sample)
```

This will break if there are any spaces in the filenames.

Another thing you shouldn't but could do is with the mapfile builtin.

```
cm(){ chmod 644 -- "${2}"; }
mapfile -t -c1 -C 'cm' < /var/tmp/sample
```

mapfile wasn't really designed for this purpose, so it's probably a lot slower than just using xargs.

Answer (score -1):

You can run the below command to change the permission of all files.

```
for i in `cat /var/tmp/sample`; do chmod 644 $i;done
```

Comment: Don't do this, instead you should [read lines rather than words](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2013), and [prevent word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086), and stop using the [legacy backtick](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006)